# XSLT coding standards

Tags: xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I require to know all coding standards of XSLT 2.0. I know some points eg., use short form of variable etc, but i want to know all coding standards of xslt. If a webpage/link/document is available containing all coding standards, it will be very useful.

Comment: I have deleted the tag "saxon" because there is nothing in your question that suggests it is a question about the Saxon product.

Answer (score -1):

When you say "coding standards" I think you mean "widely accepted good practices". I am not aware of any definitive or comprehensive set of coding standards for XSLT 2.0. There are many recommendations in various places, e.g. books and the webs, but none of them is comprehensive or definitive.